# Postgresql query to get count per months within one year

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

**In MySQL**

```
SELECT y, m, Count(users.created_date)
     FROM (
      SELECT y, m
      FROM
         (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
         (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
           UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
           UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
       LEFT JOIN users
       ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.created_date))
          AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.created_date))
     WHERE
       (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
       OR
       (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
     GROUP BY y, m;
```

**Mysql Output**

```
+------+----+----------------------+
| y    | m  | Count(users.created) |
+------+----+----------------------+
| 2012 |  5 |                 5595 |
| 2012 |  6 |                 4431 |
| 2012 |  7 |                 3299 |
| 2012 |  8 |                  429 |
| 2012 |  9 |                    0 |
| 2012 | 10 |                 3698 |
| 2012 | 11 |                 6208 |
| 2012 | 12 |                 5142 |
| 2013 |  1 |                 1196 |
| 2013 |  2 |                   10 |
| 2013 |  3 |                    0 |
| 2013 |  4 |                    0 |
+------+----+----------------------+
```

** IN POSTGRESQL QUERY**

```
SELECT to_char(created_date, 'MM'),
       count(id)
FROM users
WHERE created_date >
      date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 year'
GROUP BY 1
```

**POSTGRESQL OUTPUT**
[postgresql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UA2N.png)

May I know how to get postgresql output as like mysql output. Need to get results for current month within one year data.

Comment: Well, the data itself seems to be different, but other than that, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your MySQL query is not producing the output you specify.  It would be impossible for it to output a row with a count of 0.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sry gordon. now i change the mysql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming what you're looking for is the rows where count is 0. If that is the case you can use generate_series and a left join on your table with data:

```
    SELECT to_char(i, 'YY'), to_char(i, 'MM'),
        count(id)
    FROM generate_series(now() - INTERVAL '1 year', now(), '1 month') as i
    left join users on (to_char(i, 'YY') = to_char(created_date, 'YY') 
                        and to_char(i, 'MM') = to_char(created_date, 'MM') and login_type = 1)
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: yes, should be "group by 1,2" instead of "group by 1" thank you Olaf, fixed answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. its working fine.. your saving my time. :)

Comment: when i using where condition its not working. example i have add the `where login_type=1`. that time its shows only count values greater than 0

Comment: i am getting only 9 records

Comment: Where are you putting the condition? It should go into "left join users on" block, not in the where clause. I edited the answer.

Comment: Julia, If using where condition after join statement's get last month data's only. `SELECT to_char(i, 'YYYY') as year_data, to_char(i, 'MM') as month_data, to_char(i, 'Month') as month_string, count(resident_id) as total_count FROM generate_series(now() - INTERVAL '1 year', now(), '1 month') as i 
left join residents on (to_char(i, 'YYYY') = to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') and to_char(i, 'MM') = to_char(created_at, 'MM') ) 
left join users on (users.id=residents.user_id ) 
 where resident_estate_id = 17 and users.login_type = 2
GROUP BY 1,2,3 order by year_data desc, month_data desc limit 12`