# Postgresql query to get count per months within year with multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

As per [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048369/postgresql-query-to-get-count-per-months-within-one-year) I'm used to get count based on months within one year with single table it works. But here I need get count's with two tables with relations based on user type and estate.

Sample data

**Residents table**

```
resident_id | resident_user_id  | resident_estate_id | created_at           |
31          |   75              |       1            |  2016-12-07 11:22:23 |
32          |   76              |       16           |  2016-12-07 11:22:23 |   
37          |   81              |       16           |  2016-12-07 11:22:23 |
38          |   84              |       17           |  2016-12-07 11:22:23 |
```

**Users Table**

```
id | name   | user_login_type | created_at          |
80 | rest   |   3             | 2016-12-01 15:11:08 |
81 | appu   |   2             | 2016-12-02 12:51:08 |
84 | sankar |   2             | 2016-12-06 11:11:29 |
85 | test   |   1             | 2016-12-06 15:06:57 |
```

Here we need to based on the conditions and list the data within one year. Below example queries was used to get the data's.

Example 1: If I changed the user login type 3 to 2 means also getting count was 1 for December month but need to get zero count.

```
SELECT to_char(i, 'YYYY') as year_data, to_char(i, 'MM') as month_data, to_char(i, 'Month') as month_string, count(resident_id) as ios_total_count 
FROM generate_series(now() - INTERVAL '1 year', now(), '1 month') as i 
left join residents on (to_char(i, 'YYYY') = to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') and to_char(i, 'MM') = to_char(created_at, 'MM') and resident_estate_id = 17 ) 
left join users on (users.id=residents.resident_user_id and users.user_login_type = 3) 
GROUP BY 1,2,3 order by year_data desc, month_data desc 
limit 12
```

**Output**

> ```
> "2016";"12";"December ";1
> "2016";"11";"November ";0
> "2016";"10";"October  ";0
> "2016";"09";"September";0
> "2016";"08";"August   ";0
> "2016";"07";"July     ";0
> "2016";"06";"June     ";0
> "2016";"05";"May      ";0
> "2016";"04";"April    ";0
> "2016";"03";"March    ";0
> "2016";"02";"February ";0
> "2016";"01";"January  ";0
> ```

Example 2: If I used where condition after the join statements getting December month with count also. But not getting other months within year.

```
SELECT to_char(i, 'YYYY') as year_data, to_char(i, 'MM') as month_data, to_char(i, 'Month') as month_string, count(resident_id) as ios_total_count 
FROM generate_series(now() - INTERVAL '1 year', now(), '1 month') as i 
left join residents on (to_char(i, 'YYYY') = to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') and to_char(i, 'MM') = to_char(created_at, 'MM') ) 
left join users on (users.id=residents.resident_user_id) 
where residents.resident_estate_id = 17 and users.user_login_type = 3 
GROUP BY 1,2,3 order by year_data desc, month_data desc 
limit 12
```

**Expected Output**

> ```
> "2016";"12";"December ";0
> "2016";"11";"November ";0
> "2016";"10";"October  ";0
> "2016";"09";"September";0
> "2016";"08";"August   ";0
> "2016";"07";"July     ";0
> "2016";"06";"June     ";0
> "2016";"05";"May      ";0
> "2016";"04";"April    ";0
> "2016";"03";"March    ";0
> "2016";"02";"February ";0
> "2016";"01";"January  ";0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you filter other rows with your `where residents.resident_estate_id = 17 and users.user_login_type = 3`
I assume you want instead smth like:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
  to_char(i, 'YYYY') as year_data
  , to_char(i, 'MM') as month_data
  , to_char(i, 'Month') as month_string
  , count(resident_id) 
    filter (where residents.resident_estate_id = 17 and users.user_login_type = 3) 
    over (partition by date_trunc('month',i)) as ios_total_count 
FROM generate_series(now() - INTERVAL '1 year', now(), '1 month') as i 
left join residents on (to_char(i, 'YYYY') = to_char(created_at, 'YYYY') and to_char(i, 'MM') = to_char(created_at, 'MM') ) 
left join users on (users.id=residents.resident_user_id) 
where residents.resident_estate_id = 17 and users.user_login_type = 3 
order by year_data desc, month_data desc 
limit 12
```

Comment: @ Vao, Getting December month result only. But I need here remaining months with count as zero

Comment: Sample data is updated with question. Waiting for your answer for this

Comment: please, `create table` and `insert into`